# How do I combine two columns of date and time in a csv file to 1 datetime column in pandas?

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas

I got a csv file with the following format:

date;time;DD;FH;FF;FX;T;
20110101;1;240;30;30;40;15;
20110101;2;250;30;40;60;18;
20110101;3;250;40;40;70;21;
20110101;4;250;40;30;60;20;
20110101;5;250;40;40;60;21;

I want a pandas dataframe which combines the date and time column as 1 datetime.
I tried the following code to do this:

```
deelen = pandas.read_csv('Deelen2.csv', parse_dates = [[0,1]], header = 0,   index_col = 0, delimiter=';', low_memory=False)
```

I get the following output:

```
>>> deelen.head()
          DD     FH     FF     FX      T    
date_time                                                                  
20110101 1   240     30     30     40     15             
20110101 2   250     30     40     60     18            
20110101 3   250     40     40     70     21             
20110101 4   250     40     30     60     20           
20110101 5   250     40     40     60     21
```

So date and time is combined in 1 column but it is not a datetime.

I also tried:

```
>>> deelen = pandas.read_csv('Deelen2.csv', parse_dates = {'datetime' : [0,1]}, header = 0, index_col = ['datetime'], delimiter=';')
```

But this gives a similar output:

```
           DD     FH     FF     FX      T    
datetime                                                                   
20110101 1   240     30     30     40     15            
20110101 2   250     30     40     60     18               
20110101 3   250     40     40     70     21             
20110101 4   250     40     30     60     20           
20110101 5   250     40     40     60     21
```

For some reason it is not working..
I'm working in Python 2.7 and pandas 0.18.0

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: The reason it fails is that your time column is ambiguous, what does time represent here? hours, minutes, seconds ..?

Comment: Time column is in hours. After 24 hours the date goes to 20110102, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the following works:

```
In [140]:
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""date;time;DD;FH;FF;FX;T;
20110101;1;240;30;30;40;15;
20110101;2;250;30;40;60;18;
20110101;3;250;40;40;70;21;
20110101;4;250;40;30;60;20;
20110101;5;250;40;40;60;21;"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';', dtype=({'date':str}))
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['time'], unit='H')
df

Out[140]:
       date  time   DD  FH  FF  FX   T  Unnamed: 7           date_time
0  20110101     1  240  30  30  40  15         NaN 2011-01-01 01:00:00
1  20110101     2  250  30  40  60  18         NaN 2011-01-01 02:00:00
2  20110101     3  250  40  40  70  21         NaN 2011-01-01 03:00:00
3  20110101     4  250  40  30  60  20         NaN 2011-01-01 04:00:00
4  20110101     5  250  40  40  60  21         NaN 2011-01-01 05:00:00
```

Here I specify the `dtype` for the `date` column as `str` then I convert this and construct a `TimedeltaIndex` from your time column and add this to the result of `to_datetime`

Comment: Can you maybe also explain why my ways did not work?

Comment: Your method didn't work because `201101011` cannot be parsed ambiguously, if it was just `20111001` then we can presume that the format is just `%Y%m%d` but the `1` added to this is meaningless